# QML Item, Repeater children, get child by id

Tags: qt, qml

I am working on a project which has QML something like:

```
    Item {
        id: cameraButtonBar
        ...
        Row {
            Repeater {
                id: repeaterId
                model: cameraModel.cameraPositions()

                Item {

                    Rectangle {
                        id: fullSelectedCameraMarker
                        ...
                        visible: cameraButtonBar.checkCaptured(index, false, false)
                    }
                    Rectangle {
                        id: map1SelectedCameraMarker
                        ...
                        visible: cameraButtonBar.checkCaptured(index, true, false)
                    }
                    Rectangle {
                        id: map2SelectedCameraMarker
                        ...
                        visible: cameraButtonBar.checkCaptured(index, false, true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my script "checkCaptured" JavaScript:

```
        function checkCaptured(idx, left, right) {
//Can't do anything until an image is selected
            if ( root.selectedImageIdx >= 0 ) {
                var chkItem = repeaterId.itemAt(idx);

                if ( typeof chkItem === "object" ) {
                    var marker;

                    if ( left === false && right === false ) {
                        marker = chkItem.fullSelectedCameraMarker;
                    } else if ( left === true ) {
                        marker = chkItem.map1SelectedCameraMarker;
                    } else if ( right === true ) {
                        marker = chkItem.map2SelectedCameraMarker;
                    }
                    if ( marker !== undefined ) {

                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The above isn't correct and the question is, how to I access the rectangles using the IDs in each rectangle so I get the rectangle used in the repeater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the item which contains those 3 rectangles in as a delegate, you won't have access IDs from outside of the delegate. IDs are translated to actual objects at compile time and they are not intended to reference objects at runtime.

***Anyway, manipulating delegates from the outside is not a good idea. Pass the required data to your delegate and let it decide what to do itself.***

You can assign the inner rectangles to a read-only property of the chkItem and reference them later in your function.

```
Item {
    readonly property Rectangle _fullSelectedCameraMarker: fullSelectedCameraMarker
    readonly property Rectangle _map1SelectedCameraMarker: map1SelectedCameraMarker
    readonly property Rectangle _map2SelectedCameraMarker: map2SelectedCameraMarker

    Rectangle {
        id: fullSelectedCameraMarker
        ...
        visible: cameraButtonBar.checkCaptured(index, false, false)
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: map1SelectedCameraMarker
        ...
        visible: cameraButtonBar.checkCaptured(index, true, false)
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: map2SelectedCameraMarker
        ...
        visible: cameraButtonBar.checkCaptured(index, false, true)
    }
}
```

You can also name your object using [objectName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html#objectName-prop) property and find them by iterating over [children](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#children-prop) property of the `chkItem` and checking the rectangle by its [objectName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html#objectName-prop)

```
Rectangle {

    id: fullSelectedCameraMarker
    objectName: "fullSelectedCameraMarker"
    ...
    visible: cameraButtonBar.checkCaptured(index, false, false)
}
```

```
var chkItem = repeaterId.itemAt(idx);
var chkItemChildren = chkItem.children;
// iterate over children using any machanism you prefer to filter those children
// 
for( var i = 0 ; i < chkItemChildren.length ; ++i)
{
    if(chkItemChildren[i].objectName==='fullSelectedCameraMarker'){
        // whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Note: You can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) in QML which will help a lot.

Comment: Thank you, I've since discovered a better solution which doesn't involve searching or traversing a list.

Comment: @SPlatten, I just update the answer.  manipulating delegates from the outside is not a good idea.

Comment: Why do you use `var` in `readonly property var _fullSelectedCameraMarker: fullSelectedCameraMarker`? Using `var` when you know it is an `QtObject` or even an `Item` is no good idea either.

Comment: @derM, please explain or reference somewhere explaining why it is bad. thank you.

Comment: Sure. Read section Bindings: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html - var doesn't allow optimized bindings. It is generally a good idea, to give as much information as possible to the engine, so it might chose more specialized and optimized routines.

Comment: @derM I could not find anywhere stating that *"var doesn't allow optimized bindings"* on that document

Comment: @Bersan It might be, that this has changed in the newer Qt versions. I am pretty sure, there was an issue. It is still on the best practice page https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-bestpractices.html#type-safety but not explicitly for performane reasons. What remains is the performance hint, to always choose the best fitting type to avoid expensive casting. I'd still aply this to *var* beeing less close than e.g. *Item*. However I switched from Qt 3 years ago, sadly.